# How to remove the white outline/border on Highcharts 3D on setData?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am loading a column chart in 3D with Highcharts. On the inital load, the chart works perfectly. When I use `setData()` to change the series, the chart gains an odd white outline around its edges.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

I tried a few fixes such as using `edgeColor` and `edgeWidth`, although they made no difference.

**Note:** If I hover over one of the columns, the outline is instantly removed on that particular item until `setData()` occurs again.

How can I remove this white outline from the chart?

Comment: `edgeWidth` should be working, however there is a bug. Reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4055) - thanks. As workaround, set `edgeColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hdghyz2x/

Comment: @PawełFus - The new commit (4c94d34) fixed this issue perfectly. Just have to define `edgeWidth` as `0` and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`edgeWidth` should be working, however there is a bug. Reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4055) - thanks.

As workaround, set `edgeColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)`. Demo: jsfiddle.net/hdghyz2x

Bug is fixed already by commit (`4c94d34`) - will be included in next release (4.1.5). Available already in github version: http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Pie without borders'
        },
        series: [{
            borderWidth: 0,


        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: No change unfortunately. The outline still exists.